# How to find documents by some conditions for its linked documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newby in MongoDB and I have a problem when querying a linked documents of the some documents collection.

Here is my database scheme:

```
var tagScheme = Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});
tagScheme.index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true });


var linkScheme = Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    tags: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }]
});
linkScheme.index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

I need to get a count of the appropriate links for the specified tag. I try to execute the following query:

```
dbschemes.Link.find({ 'tags.name': specifiedTagName }, function (err, links) {
    return res.send(500, err);
    alert(links.length);
});
```

This query works not properly: it always returns an empty links list. Could someone exlain me what the problem is?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support joins so you can only reference the fields of the collection you're querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JohnnyHK commented, the type of query you want to do is a relational type query and document database such as mongodb simply do not support them. Fix your schema to put that tag data directly in the link schema (nesting or "denormalizing" from a relational standpoint, which is OK in this case), then you can query it:

```
var LinkSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  tags: [String]
});
```

With that Schema, your query will work as you expect.

To address the comments below. This is a document database. It's not relational. There are trade-offs. Your data is de-normalized and it gives you some scalability and performance and you trade off flexibility of queries and data consistency to get them. If you wanted to rename a tag, a relatively rare occurrence, you'd have to do a whopping 2 database commands (a $push of the new name then a $pull of the old name) as opposed to relation where a single update command would do it.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. However I think this approach has one drawback: if we need to update some tag's name of the TagScheme we always have to remember to update tag's name of the LinkScheme. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think in Peters example he has removed the tagSchema altogether in favor of embedding the tags inside the linkschema. That means that tags between links have no relation which might and might not be ok. If you have the same tag in multiple links and you want to change them, well then you have to remember to change them all, that is how it works.